# Colouring a boxplot in R

Tags: r, data-visualization

I would like to color a barplot as follows:[image]

And I tried the following:

```
 boxplot(a,col=rep(c("blue","orange","green","pink","grey"),each=5))
```

Here "a" represents an affybatch object.

Of course the above code colors every five bars, and what I really need is color the first six in blue and the next five in orange and so on.

Or even coloring the first ten in blue and the next three in orange and the remaining again in blue would also help.I did not use ggplot because this is an affybatch object.

Comment: You may want `border` and not `col`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have no idea what `affybatch` is, but if what you're trying to do is get a character vector with the first set repeated 6 times, the next 3 5 times, and the last 6 times (as per your graph), try:

```
rep(c("blue","orange","green","pink","grey"), c(6, 5, 5, 5, 6))
#  [1] "blue"   "blue"   "blue"   "blue"   "blue"   "blue"   "orange" "orange" "orange"
# [10] "orange" "orange" "green"  "green"  "green"  "green"  "green"  "pink"   "pink"  
# [19] "pink"   "pink"   "pink"   "grey"   "grey"   "grey"   "grey"   "grey"   "grey"
```

Notice the second argument to `rep`.